# Use Entity in place of DTO inside reciever service

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, domain-driven-design, dto

Basically i have this service A that sends a DTO to the service B.

What i did is the following:

```
1) B recieves the DTO from a.
2) B converts the DTO to an Entity
3) B uses the Entity (has an in-memory db).
```

I did this way because i deal with an extremely simple domain model, and i prefer to work with the whole entity rather then the DTO or a "reduced version" of the entity, for logical and integrity reasons.

Everything works, but someone asked me to "motivate" some cases in which this can be a good and feasible approach, even if it may not be suggested by the best practices, and to extend the aforementioned brief explanation.

I'm really stuck, can you give me some hints?

Comment: If you want to store DTO in a DB you usually map it to an Entity (if you are using JPA) so that is actually expected. I am not understanding your question, can you elaborate on it? Thanks!

Comment: Someone said that my approach is not always correct, and asked me to motivate some cases in which it can be useful. They suggested me not to use the entity in (B) but to use a "reduced version" of the entity or the DTO.

Comment: "Best practices" in software engineering is generally a code for "personal biases and tastes".  Nearly every time someone brings up "that's not suggested by best practices", there's basically no explanation that will satisfy them.

Comment: But did that someone explain why is it not always correct? "They suggested me not to use the entity in (B) but to use a "reduced version" of the entity or the DTO.". What is the difference? Maybe we need to see some code so that we can help you further.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.